# Architecture to manage multiple instances of a worker?

Tags: .net, wcf, architecture, windows-services, cloud

What architecture should I go for? There is a worker process which takes messages off a queue and does processing one by one. Now I can have many windows service instances do this job, or I can have one WCF service hosted as a windows service to act as some sort of a server on which I can start a thread for each instance.

Which approach would scale better? I want viewpoints when we are talking about cloud like infrastructure where scaling is very quick, as well as, non-cloud based infrastructure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most scalable approach in cloud would be to have an instance configured with handling services with WCF or Web-api(preferable if you are designing RESTFUL services). Such instance would be scalable. In case of Azure consider this as Web-role hosted with IIS. IIS is designed to scale with incoming requests from client. Another advantage is you get IIS and asp.net infrastructure to manage security and other stuff. However if you do not need that use windows service hosted WCF or Web-api services. The web-service instances would then queue the messages or say work loads into a queue. In case of Azure the queue can be a service bus queue. Then you can have windows services or Azure worker roles to pull the work items from the queue. Usually a single worker pulls multiple messages from queue and processes it. While doing so those messages are not available to other workers. After the worker is done remove the messages or work loads from the queue. Because after some time they will be visible to other workers there are settings for visibility like in amazon SQS there is visibility timeout setting. *Pull 5 to 10 messages in a single worker and run them as a thread pool threads as a "Task" parallely.

Note that the architecture with scalable service instances at the front end, receiving incoming requests AND worker roles at the back-end clearing the work items as soon as possible is dependent on the distributed, robust and scalable queue that cloud provides like  Azure service bus and Amazon SQS. Otherwise you may have contention problems.

For in house(non-cloud) deployment normally if there is no distributed queue, here you can have the IIS hosted service instances do everything or the windows service do everything or combination. I suggeste to have HTTP services hosted with IIS to serve web pages and receive incoming requests(REST services) . IIS is good in that. However IIS pool can get recycled and may not be running if there are no requests for long time. Hence if there is requirement to run scheduled tasks or jobs windows service at the back end is good at this. Having windows service to do everything is certainly doable but from my experience using IIS and asp.net for incoming request helps in productivity. You can share the security with services and web app. I prefer to have IIS at front end and windows service at the back end. With this I do not have to manage security with windows service. Try NServiceBus for inhouse queue https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus. I have not evaluated it.

Comment: NServiceBus will only run single threaded without a paid license.

Comment: Like the idea of having some sort of a http service (hosted over iis) to do the actual "process". BUT I imagined a worker to process one message at at time - should the worker be a multi-threaded application?

Comment: Yes the worker should be multi-threaded to utilize multiple CPU's and cores on the instance. Failing so you need to run more instances to increase responsiveness of the system whereas each instance is not doing fuller utilization of CPU's and cores. This would add to the cost. There are many ways to design this. Have a single thread fetch many messages from queue and execute the messages in a thread pool in a parallel way. Or you can have multiple threads polling the queue and executing the messages. And so on. I like the first method  which makes use of thread pool threads.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply host the worker in a service and make it multithread ?
Wcf just mess up things since you have to create a dispatcher that reads the queue and invoke the services. With having the consumer working as a service you can install it on multiple machine too, configuring to read from the same queue so you scale both vertical and horizontal. I'm supposing you are using `MSMQ` or some other similar queue mechanism, if not, consider using it.

Comment: I thought about a windows service which hosts a WCF service...because I need to start threads on the service via some means of communication. So I thought WCF was it...! I didn't get what you mean by a dispatcher...what is that pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I would host each worker in a single threaded windows service. This has the following benefits:

1. Simple to code and test (no multithreading).
2. Lightweight
3. [Dispatcher](http://www.eaipatterns.com/MessageDispatcher.html) not necessary - workers will load balance with no intervention.
4. Ease of deployment/management. If there is a problem with a worker just restart service.